# Execute large sql script

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I have the following code to run SQL files.

```
string scriptDirectory = "...";
string sqlConnectionString = "...";

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(scriptDirectory);

FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.sql");

foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
{
    //StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();

    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fi.FullName);
    string script = fileInfo.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
    Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));

    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
}
```

but the problem is when any file is very large.

the solution would have all the commands in a `StringCollection` but the problem is to divide the script.

Is there some method to split an SQL file?

Split the file by `GO` is not a solution, since the file have the creation of the table and the "INSERT", and between the inserts don't have `GO`.

**Edit**

To be more clear, this is the exception to want to read large files:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was
 thrown.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
   at ConsoleApplication2.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 47
```

I could go read line by line and separates the file to find the "GO" or "INSERT / DELETE / UPDATE", but I need to know if exists any tool or SQL library to do this.

Comment: what is file size of .sql file?? is it able to Open in SSMS??

Comment: You must have some sort of batch terminator (GO) to identify individual statements or batches.  Otherwise you will need to parse the T-SQL to avoid executing an incomplete statement.

Comment: Still I haven't understood what is the problem that forces you to split the file.

Comment: The question is unclear. You don't say what error you get and at what point. But generally: either edit your files so they are smaller or use [sqlcmd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx).

Comment: And where exactly your method crashes? Could you provide a sample file and the exception details? I cannot understand how a file containing only SQL code could throw an exception (should be reasonably small).

Comment: @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP Ok, but usually within a few scripts have multiple INSERT, and between them I don't have batch terminator GO

Comment: @TomT I know I can use the tool like Sqlcmd.exe or run small file. My problem is with large files that normally has INSERTS or UPDATES. 

And this is a part of a program, my goal is to have a folder with many scripts sorted by name and run them all in that order.

Comment: @TamasIonut I edited the answer so you can see more clearly my problem.

Comment: In case we cannot solve your issue... why do you have enormous scripts full of `INSERT`s. Is it an option to load the data via delimited file instead?

Comment: If each `INSERT` statement is on an individual line, then you can use ReadLine then execute a batch of multiple statements at an arbitrary count.  The issue is when statements span multiple lines, you won't know when you have a complete `INSERT` statement.  You must have batch terminators in the source file to handle that situation.  Consider using an alternate method like SqlBulkCopy for such a large number of rows.

Comment: Do not make your batch too large. e.g. > 1 or 2GB. Add `GO` to separate into multiple batches

Comment: yes, I'm know, but I should like use some library o SQL Server's utils like I use in SQL command line with "SQLCMD"